# Getting Cell Value from Closed Workbooks in a Directory - How to Loop Through All Existing Files?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code to retrieve a specific cell in a closed workbook when I specify the directory. I'm trying to get this code to loop through all the existing workbooks in said directory, retrieving the same cell from each file.

This is the code I have so far with the loop (I'm including the function used as well):

```
Private Function GetValueFromClosedWorkbook(path, file, sheet, ref)    
    Dim arg As String, xFolder As String

    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"

    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValueFromClosedWorkbook = "File not found."
        Exit Function
    End If

    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
    Range(ref).Address(, , xlR1C1)         'create the argument
    GetValueFromClosedWorkbook = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function


Sub TestGetValueFromClosedWorkbook()        
    Dim p As String, xFolder As String        
    Dim s As String, a As String, f(1 To 2) As String, z As Long

    xFolder = "\\generic path"

    For z = 1 To 2
        s = "Sheet1"
        a = "A1"
        p = xFolder '& "\*.xlsx"
        f(z) = Dir(p & "\*.xlsx")  

        Do While f(z) <> ""
            ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (z + 7)) = GetValueFromClosedWorkbook(p, f(z), s, a)   
            f(z) = Dir()
        Loop
    Next z
End Sub
```

This gets the correct cell, and then pastes in the active worksheet in cell A8.

The only issue is that when it loops through the second file, it still gets the cell from the first file. Why is that happening? Or how can I ensure that the second loop it retrieves the cell from the second workbook?

Comment: Not completely sure, as unable to test... but `Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)` evaluates to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Range("A1").Address....` . is that what you intended?

Comment: No, just noticed that-- thank you! I changed it and edited the code above. The same issue still persists (pastes the value from the same closed workbook through each iteration of z)

Comment: You only have 2 files as it looks (unless I`m wrong) ... is it possible you have the same value in the second file? Otherwise I would recommend: 1. name those variables more clearly (p,f,s,a is just not readable). 2. step through code and see what values you are passing to your function. 3. (less important, but still good practice) declare your variables in the function i.e.: path as string, file as string, sheet as string, ref as string.

Comment: Is because of the way you constructed those 2 loops, you are overwriting the values... Let me see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loops were a bit messed up, and you were overwriting the values. Please see below corrected code:

```vb
Sub TestGetValueFromClosedWorkbook()

    Dim p As String, xFolder As String

    Dim s As String, a As String, f As String, z As Long

    xFolder = "\\generic path"

    s = "Sheet1"
    a = "A1"
    p = xFolder '& "\*.xlsx"

    f = Dir(p & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While f <> ""

        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (z + 7)) = GetValueFromClosedWorkbook(p, f, s, a)

        f = Dir()
        z = z + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up taking your advice (in an earlier comment) and re-made the code using FileSystemObject and got it to work. But your post answers the original question, thanks!