VBA Function to link value from another WB
I had the following formula in a cell on my WB01
='\\000.000.0.000\Public\DOCS\Hualley\[FLUXO CAIXA HINDY - 108.xlsm]CONTAS MES'!BA80'

I'm trying to turn it into a function because I'm going to add a few more steps to make this formula more dynamic to meet a request, but I'm stuck because I can't get the function to open the WB. My code so far (note that it won't be my final code, I'll do a lot more things still)
Function SearchCell(NameWB As String) As Variant

    Dim DirBase As String
    DirBase = "\\000.000.0.000\Public\DOCS\Hualley\"
    
    'Name WB in cell (A1 = "FLUXO CAIXA HINDY - 108.xlsm")
    Dim DirFull As String
    DirFull = DirBase & NameWB
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = "CONTA MES"
    
    Dim CellLocation As String
    CellLocation = "BA80"
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(DirFull, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    
    SearchCell = ws.Range(CellLocation).Value
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Function

Is it possible to get the same result as the formula in a function in this case? For example, every time WB01 is opened, the formulas are updated, WB01 opens all the spreadsheets to which the formulas refer and updates their values. I would like to know if it is possible to get the same result with a function.

A function used in a UDF can't open a workbook.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.

See here for alternative method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318006/getting-cell-value-from-closed-workbooks-in-a-directory-how-to-loop-through-al
